# Wpf command not fire

Tags: wpf, command

i know there are many examples about my question, but i can't find out what is wrong.
I have a simple test button and if im using in the Command the Path=DataContext specification, my button is enabled and do not stop in the breakpoint for the command getter.
If im not using the Path=DataContext specification, my button is not enabled but it stop in the breakpoint for the command getter. Its very crazy

Maybe anyone can help me.

This is my RelayCommand class:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region ... vars
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        #endregion

        #region ... constructor
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid action");

            this._execute = execute;
            this._canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        #endregion

        #region ... properties
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ... methods
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this._canExecute == null ? true : false;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this._execute(parameter);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

In my ViewModel:

```
 private RelayCommand _testButtonClickCommand;
        public ICommand TestButtonClickCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_testButtonClickCommand == null)
                    _testButtonClickCommand = new RelayCommand(param => TestButtonClick(), param => CanTestButtonClick());

                return _testButtonClickCommand;
            }
        }
public bool CanTestButtonClick()
        {
            return true;
        }
        public void TestButtonClick()
        {
            
        }
```

And in the XML:

```
<StackPanel 
            x:Name="buttonList"
            Grid.Row="4" 
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            Margin="5">
            <Button 
               Content="Test" 
               Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.TestButtonClickCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

1. Remove `DataContext` from .xaml to `Command="{Binding Path=TestButtonClickCommand}"/>` it's no use in this case.

and Add:  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModels" - path to ViewModel and add DataContext this way:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

2. Fix in RelayCommand - to fix CanTestButtonClick

   ```
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this._canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }
   ```

This should fix your problem.